# Access Related Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Consider the following simple models...

```
//models/invoice.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    //created_by: DS.attr('number'),   //points to a user.id
    created_by: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true, inverse: created_by}),

    //approved_by: DS.attr('number'),  //also points to a user.id
    approved_by: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true, inverse: approved_by}),

});

//models/user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
    created_by: DS.belongsTo('invoice', {async: true, inverse: 'created_by'}),
    approved_by: DS.belongsTo('invoice', {async: true, inverse: 'approved_by'})
});
```

And relevant JSON...

```
{
    "invoices": 
     [
       {    
          "id": "2",
          "created_by": "103",
          "approved_by": "109",
          .....
```

I am trying to get the **Names** values for each of the ID values in any given Invoice record.

```
# | Created | Approved
--------------------------
2 | Jim     | Bobby  
3 | Sue     | Betty
```

I can get the **approved_by** relationship to populate data in my template....

```
{{item.approved_by.id}} {{item.approved_by.name}}
```

but not **created_by**...
    {{item.created_by.id}} {{item.created_by.name}}

I can see some data being rendered in the template then it goes away.
I can see the correct requests sent off to the API...

```
http://localhost:4200/RESTAPI/v1/users/110
http://localhost:4200/RESTAPI/v1/users/200
```

My question:  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to check this http://emberjs.com/api/data/#method_belongsTo

Comment: Please don't completely change your question. It renders the answers given meaningless to other people. Add an UPDATE section, with your latest code, etc. You may also consider accepting an answer which resolved the immediate issue, and create another question if you're running into a new issue.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I wont do that again.

Answer (score 0):

This is where Ember relationships come into play. In your particular example, you need to tell Ember that your Invoice model *belongs to* your User model. And, vice versa, your User model can *have many* invoices related to it.

The actual syntax for this can be found here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_one-to-many

Once you wire that up properly, you can do something like:

```
 invoice.get('user.name')
```